# Why doesn't an invalid exception name in an "except" statement cause a NameError immediately?

Tags: python

Consider this example, with a deliberate typo:

```
try:
    print("Hello!")
    raise ValueError("?")
except ValueErro:
    print("Error!")
finally:
    print("World!")
```

The handling of the explicitly raised `ValueError` results in a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: ?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'ValueErro' is not defined
```

However, if a `ValueError` is **not** raised:

```
try:
    print("Hello!")
except ValueErro:
    print("Error!")
finally:
    print("World!")
```

then **no exception occurs**; `Hello!` and `World!` are simply printed.

**Why is there no `NameError`** caused by the typo `ValueErro` (no such name exists)? Shouldn't this have been detected ahead of time?

Can I use a different syntax to ensure that the problem is caught ahead of time?

Comment: That's the explicit behavior I'm trying to highlight.
I caught this because I had a typo in a larger program that would silently pass over the except block where the code should have flowed through.

argparse.ArgumentTypeError vs argparser.ArgumentTypeError.

The confusion lies in that NameErrors like this should probably be caught at parsing time rather than runtime.

Comment: What's the problem then ?

Comment: NameErrors can't be caught at parse time. For all Python knows, some other code it can't see is intended to bind the `ValueErro` name in the cases where that expression would be evaluated.

Comment: This is one of the tradeoffs you make with a dynamic language. If you don't like it, you can look for static analysis tools, but they can't catch everything.

Comment: Apparently the `except` clauses are evaluated in a lazy way, only when there is an exception that must be handled. Try this code: `try: pass except 1/0: print('hello')`. The code runs just fine.

Comment: @DYZ Do you have a source for where except clauses are described to be lazily evaluated?

Comment: I do not (that's why I said "apparently"). But it is apparent from what we see.

Comment: @erhlee.bird A look at your prorgram's bytecode should tell you.

Comment: However, one would expect the interpreter would parse `except ValueErro` and bork, even if it's just skipping it. However, Ruby does exactly the same thing: `begin; puts "Hello"; rescue NameErro; puts "Error!"; finally; puts "World!"; end` does not make a fuss. Curious. Probably the lazy evaluation of `except` is an optimisation, for languages where exceptions are commonly used for flow control?

Comment: So, what you're "complaining" is that python can't find an error unles that part of the code is run. I thought this was a feature rather than a bug.

Comment: @Amadan: The parser doesn't care whether the symbols it's parsing correspond to bound or unbound names. `except` clause exception types aren't evaluated unless there's an exception to catch, and unevaluated code doesn't throw NameErrors. [You can put much weirder stuff than `ValueErro` there.](https://ideone.com/rhJ5P8)

Comment: It's the same as with `NameError` **anywhere else**. `def example(): return this_name_is_definitely_not_defined` doesn't cause a problem until `example` is called. Similarly, the name `ValueErro` in the example isn't looked up until it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a comment from @DYZ, I found the right search terms to get the answer.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

> The try statement works as follows.
>
> - First, the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except keywords) is executed.
> - If no exception occurs, the except clause is skipped and execution of the try statement is finished.

Another resource exploring this problem.

https://dbaktiar-on-python.blogspot.com/2009/07/python-lazy-evaluation-on-exception.html

-

My Solution moving forward:

```
# Explicitly bind the Exception Names in a non-lazy fashion.
errors = (KeyboardInterrupt, ValueErro) # Caught!
try:
    print("Hello!")
    raise ValueError("?")
except errors:
    print("Error!")
finally:
    print("World!")
```

-

tl;dr - The except clauses are entirely skipped if the try clauses executes without exception.

Comment: @DYZ - if you'd like to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I really don't get what your question is and how is this the answer.

Comment: @tglaria - I wanted to better understand why the `ValueErro` name was not being evaluated during the overall try-except definition and find a way to force it to resolve at an earlier time. 

I had previously assumed that the entire try-except block had a single symbol resolution time. That not being the case, the links in here provide the explicit rules behind the observed lazy evaluation.

Comment: This won't protect against accidentally typing `except erors:`, though. It only kicks the can down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions can be defined at run time. Example:

myexcept.py contains:

```
class ValueErro(Exception):
    pass
```

Your program slightly modified:

```
import_myexcept = False
if import_myexcept:
    from myexcept import ValueErro

try:
    print("Hello!")
    raise ValueError("?")
except ValueErro:
    print("Error!")
finally:
    print("World!")
```

This behaves just like your program: `NameError: name 'ValueErro' is not defined`.

But change: `import_myexcept = True`, and by the time the `except ValueErro:` statement is encountered, the `ValueErro` exception is defined and no NameError occurs.